# Get no. of possible/visible lines on TextView

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to get the number of lines a TextView is capable of showing?
I want to use it as a log view, adding new lines to the bottom and removing the oldest from the top...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

refer these apis in `TextView`
`getHeight`
`getLineHeight`

Dividing the height by line height will give you the max number of lines possible.

Something like 
`(tv.getHeight() - tv.gettoppadding() - tv.getbottompadding())/tv.getLineHeight();`